# VBA Excel Macro to Clear All Comboboxes and a Checkbox

Tags: vba, excel

I basically am trying to assign a macro to a command button that clears certain cells and also a few comboboxes and checkbox on an active sheet but cannot get my macro/command to run successfully.  Please help! This would be greatly appreciated.  My code looks like this so far:

```
Sub Macro4()

Sheet4.Select
Range("B3").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("B4").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("C13").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("C14").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("F8").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("J8").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("B23").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("J3").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("G4").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheet4.ComboBox4.Select
ComboBox4 = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: are your ComboBoxes of `Form Controls` or `ActiveX Controls` ?

Comment: If it was a Form Control it would have been DropBox4 I think?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Sheet4.ComboBox4.Value = ""
```

Also as a general hint, instead of using Selections like:

```
range("A1").select
selection.clearcontents
```

you can combine these lines and just tell it to clear the contents directly:

```
range("A1").clearcontents
```

Answer (score 1):

I setup a Range named **ClearRng**, which consists of all the cells you want to clear contents from.

Also, the code loops through all `OLEObjects` in "**Sheet4**", and checks if they are `ComboBox` type, if they are it clears the content from it.

(this code is intended to `ActiveX Controls`, not `User_Form Controls`)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro4()

Dim Sht                 As Worksheet
Dim ClearRng            As Range
Dim Obj                 As OLEObject

' set Sht variable to "Sheet4"
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")

' set all the cells you want to clear in one Range
Set ClearRng = Sht.Range("B3,B4,C13,C14,F8,J8,B23,J3,G4")

ClearRng.ClearContents       

' loop thourgh all OLE objects in "Sheet4"
For Each Obj In Sht.OLEObjects
    ' for debug > check name if ActiveX Control
    Debug.Print Obj.Name

    ' if OLE Object is type ComboBox
    If Obj.progID = "Forms.ComboBox.1" Then
       Obj.ListFillRange = ""  ' clear all contents of the ComboBox
    End If

End Sub
```

**Option 2:** to Clear contents of `ComboBox`, use the Sheet4 object type, then use the code below:

```
With Sheet4.ComboBox4
    .Clear
End With
```

Comment: `Obj.ListFillRange = ""` does not work, what else can I do to truncate `all` comboboxes? The `obj` is probably not a `combobox` object, so `.clear` will not work.

Comment: Strange that the `@` does not work here to address the responser. This seems an issue for the SO people.